# Проблема с непонятной логикой cookies в Yii2 Advanced

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с непонятной работой в cookies Yii2.
Создаю компонент, который будет записывать данные с UTM-меток в куки.

Данные берутся с URL, и дело в том, что Yii2 вместо моего содержимого *(&utm_source=123456)* записывает произвольное, и при попытке "достучаться" к куке - получаю в ответ `null`.

Такое ощущение, будто происходит перезапись на null'евое значение где-то.

Компонент:

```
<?php

namespace app\components;

use Yii;
use yii\base\BootstrapInterface;
use yii\web\Cookie;

class Utm implements BootstrapInterface
{


    public function bootstrap($app)
    {

        if(!Yii::$app->request->get('utm_source')){
            Yii::$app->response->cookies->add(new Cookie([
                'name' => 'utm_source',
                'value' => Yii::$app->request->get('utm_source'),
            ]));
        }


    }
}
```

Код, который использую для взаимодействия с куками:

```
$url = null;
$cookies = Yii::$app->request->cookies;

var_dump($cookies->get('utm_source')); // в результате null

if($cookies->has('utm_source')) { // в результате false
    $url .= "&utm_source=".$cookies->get('utm_source'); // запись в переменную, это чисто для себя, в дальнейшем это будет использоваться
}
```

UPD:
Грешил на то, что не считывает по какой-то причине данные с $_GET, но проверил и всё нормально вернуло:

```
var_dump(Yii::$app->request->get('utm_source')); //вернуло string(6) "123456"
```

Comment: Что то упускаю, или логика странная, если нет в url - utm_source то не создает куку, то не добавит в урл utm_source, то нет в url - utm_source, то не создает куку .... ну и так по кругу

Comment: @Bookin, если в URL нет utm_source - ничего не происходит, ничего не записывается. Но если в URL есть utm_source - создаётся одноименная кука.

Comment: `if(!Yii::$app->request->get('utm_source')){` а зачем у вас тут отрицание?

Comment: @Visman, `get()` при отсутствии utm_source должно вернуть false Соответственно, запись в куку происходит если не равно false, т.е. имеет содержимое.

Comment: То есть если у вас в get нет utm_source, то вы ее записываете в куку? :) Записываете null!

Comment: @Visman, действительно, починил, работает, спасибо большое! Что-то заторомозил :(